# radio buttons and webapp2

Tags: python, html, webapp2

Below is the form in **quiz.html** file.
I don't know how to get the value from a clicked button after submitting the form and writing in /testform.

```
<html>
    <form method="post"  action="/testform">
        Q1. where are you from?<br>
        <input type = "radio" name = "q_1" value ="a">Iraklio</br>
        <input type = "radio" name = "q_1" value = "b">Patra</br>
        <input type = "radio" name = "q_1" value = "c">Athens</br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "submit" >
    </form>
</html>
```

**Python script:**

```
import webapp2
import jinja2


templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader( searchpath="./")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment( loader=templateLoader )


class quiz(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
                 TEMPLATE_FILE = "quiz.html"
                 template = templateEnv.get_template( TEMPLATE_FILE )
                 x = template.render()
                 self.response.write(x)

class test(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def post(self):
                ans = self.request.get('value')
                print ans
                self.response.write(ans)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',quiz),('/testform',test)]
,debug = True)

def main():
        from paste import httpserver
        httpserver.serve(app, host='127.0.0.1', port='8080')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My objective was:
to print in a subpage (/testform) the letter of the clicked button after submitting the post form.

My mistake was that in : `ans = self.request.get('value')` , i had to replace `'value'` with `'q_1'`.Then it worked fine.!!

p.s. https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/request.html